# Html not recognizing JavaScript (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm making a Chrome Extension and my HTML is not picking up any JavaScript.

HTML Head:

```
<script src="application.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery (The alerts are here for testing purposes):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
alert("hello");
$(".box").click(function () {

  alert("box");
  $("webview").show(1000); 
  $(".content").slideUp();

});

$(".webHome").click(function () {
  $(".content").show(1000);
});
});
```

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",

  "name": "ChromeApps",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
  "128": "logo.png"
},
"app": {
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js", "application.js" ],
    "persistent": false
  }
},
"permissions": ["webview"],
"kiosk_enabled": true
```

All my files are definitely in the same folder. I feel like there is something in the manifest that I'm missing.

Comment: First of all try loading jQuery **brefore** application.js and than explain `html is not picking up any JavaScript` and check for console errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your manifest is a manifest for a Chrome App, not an Extension.

With that in mind, [Chrome Apps **cannot use remote code**](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy), so you can't include jQuery from a CDN.

You need to include a local copy of `jquery.min.js` and include it in the same way as `application.js`.

Also, don't forget that order matters: you need to load jQuery before using it.

Comment: As an aside, it seems that including `application.js` **as a background script** is a bad idea.

Comment: I have done those things, and have put ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
  "application.js",
  "jquery.min.js"
], in the manifest, still not working.

Comment: `web_accessible_resources` is invalid in a Chrome app.

Comment: Iv'e taken that out, its still not working, do you want to see more of my code? Really is beyond me at the minute.